# Get specific value from a message in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my application, after performing all the action, if i press save button, i'm receiving the below message.

`Deal 0000195734 has been saved
Sales order 12345 has been created`

Now i want to get only the numeric value from the above message. Not the text part.
Eg : 0000195734 & 12345

Because i need to search using the above created value.

Please find the below code

`String deal_num = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='CLine1']/span[4]")).getText();
System.out.println(deal_num);
deal_num = Deal 0000195734 has been saved`

I am using java with Selenium Web Driver.

Kindly suggest

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 1):

**String deal_num = Deal 0000195734 has been saved.**

You can easily replace characters before and after numeric values in two steps.

*First step will replace the characters before numeric value with space.*

```
deal_num= deal_num.replace("Deal "," ");
```

*Second step will replace the characters after numeric value with space.*

```
deal_num= deal_num.replace(" has been saved"," ");
```

In the same way you can do it for second message of *Sales order*.

- Remember to achieve the same there are also other ways but the one i
  suggested you is the most easiest way i found.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in same format always you can achieve it by:

```
String deal_num = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='CLine1']/span[4]")).getText();
deal_num = deal_num.split(" ")[1] // splitting on the basis of space and taking index 2 where your numbers will be available
```

and similarly for next line also that you provided.

Comment: Hi Vivek,
Thanks it is working.
But for the string "Sales order 12345 has been created" if i give it as deal_num = deal_num.split(" ")[2]; it is giving the error as "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:"

Kindly help

Comment: Have you stored it in any other variable? if u r using deal_num then deal_num.split(" ")[1] has already made it to single string so splitting it will give u one index only. You need to save the given string to another one and then perform split.

Answer (score 0):

User regular expressions to extract number from string.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("There are more than -2 and less than 12 numbers here");
while (m.find()) {
 System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

`-?` matches a leading negative sign -- optionally. `\d` matches a digit, and we need to write `\` as `\\` in a Java String though. So, `\\d+` matches 1 more more digits