# Selenium WebDriver how to verify Text from Span Tag

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to verify the text in the span by using WebDriver. There is the span tag:

```
<span class="value">
    /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja
</span>
```

I tried something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja']'"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span./Company Home/IRP/tranzycja"));
```

but none of this work.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

More code:

```
<span id="uniqName_64_0" class="alfresco-renderers-PropertyLink alfresco-renderers-Property pointer small" data-dojo-attach-point="renderedValueNode" widgetid="uniqName_64_0">
    <span class="inner" tabindex="0" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:onLinkClick">
    <span class="label">
        In folder: 
    </span>
    <span class="value">
        /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja
    </span>
</span>
```

uniqName shouldn't be a target because are a lot of them and they are change.

There is a full html code:
http://www.filedropper.com/spantag

Comment: Can you post few more HTML code snippet of before and after span tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am assuming you are trying to verify the text in the *span* tag.

i.e '/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja'

Try Below code

```
String expected String = "/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja";

String actual_String = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='alfresco-renderers-PropertyLink alfresco-renderers-Property pointer small']//span[@class='value']")).getText();

if(expected String.equals(actual_String))

{

System.out.println("Text is Matched");

}

else

{

System.out.println("Text is not Matched");

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rupesh. Yes, exactly, I'm trying to verify the text in the span. Your method is great, but in my case, it gives me "Text is not Matched" every time, even if the text in span exist on the website. Any other ideas?

Comment: @euro - what is the value of actual_String using Rupesh's code example?

Comment: Hi Guys! Every time the value is different:
1) irp_role;;
2) RSW_ZAMOWIENIA_OPT_120212_06_A.sql
3) PCB_IRP_20100720_v1[1].1.3.pdf
4) IRP Data Model v1 3 01 03 2007.rtf
and so on, so this method still not catch the valid value.
Some other ideas Guys?
Thx.

Comment: You had right Guys, there is more than one span tag with class="value".
There is a full html code: http://www.filedropper.com/spantag
I'm interesting only about first attempt of /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja.
How can I go about doing that?

Comment: @euro  : Yes i have changed the xpath in my answer, please try the new code and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh! Now the xpath read the correct tag, GREAT!!!
But I still have i problem. If the value of actual_String is e.g.
- /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja/ZPRO/Dokumentacja techniczna
- /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja/HLD_HLDS_LLD/Twins ITN
or sth similar (which is correct, because it contains String expected = "/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja";) the if-then statement gives me the output "Text is not Matched". How to change this if-then statement to recognize such a actual_String examples like as above?

Comment: Ok,  I used a substring method and it seems to be alright, but, once again, I have another problem. How to continue my test if the finding element is not on the site (if the element is not on the site, then the driver.findElement(By.xpath... is not work - because then I am on other site where this special span tag is not exist). Is it possible to do this by another if-then statement?

Comment: @euro : Good to know that you're able to detect the correct web-element, Will appreciate if you mark my code as answer,  about the second question , i will suggest use assertion "assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Text-you-are-Looking-for"));" or Try -catch block. and about the expression change syntax please refer link below..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340532/get-specific-value-from-a-message-in-selenium-webdriver/29345287#29345287

Comment: Thanks again Rupesh! I used a try catch block and it's doing well. I have another question. How to change Your xpath to find through every class='alfresco-renderers-PropertyLink alfresco-renderers-Property pointer small' and every span='value', because for that moment it only search first statement of these conditions. 
You know, sometimes expected _String is not on the first line, but could be also in further lines. 
-first line - <span id="uniqName_64_0" class="alfresco...
-second line - <span id="uniqName_64_1" class="alfresco...
-third line <span id="uniqName_64_2" class="alfresco...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using xpath ('some text' can be replaced by variable like @Rupesh suggested):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/span[@class='value'][normalize-space(.) = 'some text']"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/span[@class='value'][contains(text(),'some text')]"))
```

(Be aware that this xpath will find first matching element, so if there are span elements with text 'some text 1' and 'some text 2', only first occurrence will be found.)

Of course, those two methods will throw NoSuchElementException if element (with defined text) is not found on page. If you're using Java and if needed, you can easy catch that error and print proper message.

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to want to use something like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja'])).getText();
```

the getText(); will get the text within that span

Comment: I think parenthesis should be closed after the expression and there are missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One possible xpath to find that `<span>` element :

```
//span[normalize-space(.) = '/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text() method inside Xpath. I hope this will resolve your problem

```
String str1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='/Company Home/IRP/tranzycja']")).getText();
System.out.println("str1");
```

Output = /Company Home/IRP/tranzycja